# Parsing with regular expressions

Tags: regex, ios, regexkitlite

I have some text like

```
some text [http://abc.com/a.jpg] here will be long text 

can be multiple line breaks again [http://a.com/a.jpg] here will be other text

blah blah
```

Which I need to transform into

```
<div>some text</div><img src="http://abc.com/a.jpg"/><div>here will be long text 

can be multiple line breaks again</div><img src="http://a.com/a.jpg"/><div>here will be other text

blah blah</div>
```

To get the `<img>` tags, I replaced `\[(.*?)\]` with `<img src="$1"/>`, resulting in

```
some text<img src="http://abc.com/a.jpg"/>here will be long text 

can be multiple enters again<img src="http://a.com/a.jpg"/>here will be other text

blah blah
```

However, I have no idea how to wrap the text in a `<div>`.

I'm doing everything on the iPhone with RegexKitLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest approach:

1. Replace all occurrences of `\[(.*?)\]` with `</div><img src="$1"/><div>`
2. Prepend a `<div>`
3. Append a `</div>`

That does have a corner case where the result starts or ends with `<div></div>`, but this probably doesn't matter.

If it does, then:

1. Replace all occurrences of `\](.*?)\[` with `]<div>$1</div>[`
2. Replace all occurrences of `\[(.*?)\]` with `<img src="$1"/>`

Comment: Thanks :) but any other idea will be nice. Coz I was using this logic already.